# Post new iframe src, monitor and reload on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, reload

I've read multiple Q&A on here regarding changing the iframe src URL via form post etc however none seem to have what I'm trying to accomplish. Using jQuery or JavaScript if possible.

So I have **index.html** which contains 1 iframe.

```
<html>
..
<iframe id="stream" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling=no allowtransparency=true frameborder="0" framespacing="0" webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen name="stream" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://youtu.be/JIdaZ2EJ1Zk">
..
etc
</html>
```

And on a separate page I have a **form.html** file which will let me post a new src url for the iframe.
I'm trying to change the src of the iframe in **index.html** from **form.html** with no luck.

For example the user will be watching the initial iframe src.

Running maybe a JavaScript check every 5 seconds to "**detect iframe src change**" or a better method is welcome.
it will then reload the iframe to the url from the form post. any help is greatly appreciated sorry for the long winded question I'm bad at explaining..

**Nutshell:** form post new src url, detect src url change and reload only the iframe with new url src.

Comment: well. Do you use some database on the beckend? Or how do you set the url? If via js, you can sue an anchor in your **form.html** using the `target` attribute, so when you change url in form.html, index.html will be reloaded

Comment: @GiuServ there 2 html files uploaded to local server perhaps i will need to use php or ajax?

Comment: I just posted you a simple example of solution, using php and no javascript at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also make it with a single page in php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
?>
    <iframe id="stream" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
        scrolling=no allowtransparency=true frameborder="0"
        framespacing="0" webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
        name="stream" width="100%" height="100%"
        src="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">
<?php
    }else{
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type='text' value="" name="url" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Show" />
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Note that it's a very fast and simple solution, using a single page.

You could also still use 2 differents page, index and form, and maybe retrive the url for the iframe from the address

```
http://blablbal?url=foo
```

and access the url attribute with $_GET

**note** 
There is no refresh in this way, but you could keep the form for setting the url always visible and still use a single page solution:

```
<html>  
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type='text' name="url" 
            value="<?php echo(isset($_POST['url'])? $_POST['url']:'');?>" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Show" />
    </form>
    <hr>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    ?>
        <iframe id="stream" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
            scrolling=no allowtransparency=true frameborder="0"
            framespacing="0" webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
            name="stream" width="100%" height="100%"
            src="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</html>
```